# How to add python executable path for sagemaker SKLearn python SDK?

Tags: scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

When I run train.py via SKLearn estimater in sagemaker python SDK it runs using default python executable path of sagemaker which is /miniconda3/bin/python

I want to run using another python executable path which is /miniconda3/envs/interplay-env/bin/python3

How to set this in sagemaker SKLearn estimator?

Below is current configuration of sagemaker estimator

```
sklearn_estimator = SKLearn(
            entry_point=train.py,
            role=role,
            instance_count=1,
            instance_type="ml.c5.xlarge",
            framework_version=FRAMEWORK_VERSION,
            base_job_name=training_job_name,
            hyperparameters={
                "parameters_dict": parameters_dict1,
                "features": features,
                "target": target,
                "project_path":project_path,
                "bucket_name":bucket_name,
            }
            
        )
```

I tried setting the executable path in entry_point like below. But it doesn't work.

```
sklearn_estimator = SKLearn(
            entry_point=["/miniconda3/envs/interplay-env/bin/python3",train_file_name],
            role=role,
            instance_count=1,
            instance_type="ml.c5.xlarge",
            framework_version=FRAMEWORK_VERSION,
            base_job_name=training_job_name,
            hyperparameters={
                "parameters_dict": parameters_dict1,
                "features": features,
                "target": target,
                "project_path":project_path,
                "bucket_name":bucket_name,
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to do that. By Default SageMaker runs the code in a container and provides a separate conda environment for your code to run. If you need additional libraries you can have a requirements.txt and add the dependent libraries into it. Later you will add another attribute in your SKlearn Estimator called source_dir point to a folder that will contain your entrypoint script and the requirements.txt

Comment: Currently, I'm doing it in the way you mentioned. But I want to maintain separate environments for separate training scripts. Therefore I wanted virtual environments to be created and pointed when the script is running.